# Change radio button based on other radio button's value

Tags: javascript, html

How do I deal with this behaviour:

[image]

Relevant HTML:

```
    <p>
        Player 1: <input type="text" name="player1Name">
        <input type="radio" name="option1" value="X" id='option1X'/> X
        <input type="radio" name="option1" value="O" id='option1O' /> O

    </p>
    <p>
        Player 2: <input type="text" name="player2Name">
        <input type="radio" name="option2" value="X" id='option2X' /> X
        <input type="radio" name="option2" value="O" id='option2O'/> O

    </p>
```

Here's what I have tried:

```
const option2X = document.getElementById('option2X');
const option2O = document.getElementById('option2O');
const option1X = document.getElementById('option1X');
const option1O = document.getElementById('option1O');

function checkRadios(option1, option2, option3) {
    option1.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if(option1.checked && option2.checked)
        option3.setAttribute('checked', 'true'); 
    });
}

checkRadios(option1X, option2X, option2O); 
checkRadios(option1O, option2O, option2X); 
checkRadios(option2X, option1X, option1O); 
checkRadios(option2O, option1O, option1X);
```

This works for the first time and then it stops working.
I  checked the debugger, and the reason is that option3's value changes somehow.
Player1's radios are option1X and option1O.

What I want:
If an option is clicked by user A and the same option has already been taken by another user (B), then the other user's (B's) radio should change.
I tried changing the 'click' event to 'change' and that also didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

I have used `addEventListener` method for calling a function that checks another radio button. There exists no need for clearing selected checkbox. This is because as soon as you check one radio button out of the two, other automatically gets deselected.

I have also used a function to check if both the two options are selected or not. If they are not, `null` is returned and then nothing happens. But if both of them are selected, manipulation of selected radio button takes place.

```
const option2X = document.getElementById('option2X');
const option2O = document.getElementById('option2O');
const option1X = document.getElementById('option1X');
const option1O = document.getElementById('option1O');

check = () => document.querySelector('input[name="option1"]:checked') && document.querySelector('input[name="option2"]:checked');

option1X.addEventListener("change", function() {if (check()) option2O.checked = true});
option2X.addEventListener("change", function() {if (check()) option1O.checked = true});

option1O.addEventListener("change", function() {if (check()) option2X.checked = true});
option2O.addEventListener("change", function() {if (check()) option1X.checked = true});
```

**Note:** This starts working from MS Edge 12. For lower versions, change the `check` function to

```
function check() {
    return document.querySelector('input[name="option1"]:checked') && document.querySelector('input[name="option2"]:checked');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may simply allow only the first player to choose the letter.

Anyway, you can simply change the checked property of the radio buttons:

```
switch (player1.choice) {
    case "X":
        player2RadioX.checked = false;
        player2RadioX.enabled = false;
        player2RadioO.checked = true;
        player2RadioO.enabled = true;
        break;

    case "O":
        player2RadioO.checked = false;
        player2RadioO.enabled = false;
        player2RadioX.checked = true;
        player2RadioX.enabled = true;
        break;
}
```